# Add a number to a number located in a string in BASH

Tags: sql, bash, parsing

I have a sql file that I need to modify so that the ID section of a row is increased by 3. How can I increased the ID field and keep the rest of the line as it is in BASH?
Ex:

```
insert into info.names values (35, 'John', 'C', 2);
insert into info.names values (36, 'Mark', 'C', 1);
insert into info.names values (37, 'Bob', 'C', 5);
```

I need to add 3 to 35, 36 and 37, so that they become 38,39,40. SO the output would be

```
insert into info.names values (38, 'John', 'C', 2);
insert into info.names values (39, 'Mark', 'C', 1);
insert into info.names values (40, 'Bob', 'C', 5);
```

I'd like to do this in BASH.

Thank you

Comment: Only the first number in the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is the more appropriate tool for this task

```
 awk '{tmp=$5 ;sub(/^\(/, "", tmp); tmp+=3; $5="("tmp","; print $0}' file > file.new && mv file.new file
```

To explain, I'll add comments and use a more verbose format

```
 awk '{  
       # Capture the 5th field '(35,' into a tmp variable
       tmp=$5                                    
       # remove the leading "(" char
       sub(/^\(/, "", tmp)
       # add 3 to the tmp value (see note below)
       tmp+=3
       # reconstruct the 5th field adding "(" and "," as needed.
       $5="(" tmp ","
       # print the whole line
       print $0
     }' file > file.new && mv file.new file
  #     |                  |-> if no error (`&&`) overwrite the original file 
  #     |                        with the fixed file (not an awk feature)
  #     |-> write output to tmp file
```

Note that after the operation `sub(/^\(/, "", tmp)` the value of tmp is actually `35,` (note the `,` char!). When given a variable in a number context (like `+=3` ) awk will only process only the number part of that value and then perform the math operation. That is why you get `38` and not `35,3`. The line following then "put's back" the missing '(' and ',' chars.

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

Using gnu-awk you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="[^(]+|\\([0-9]+" } {$2="(" substr($2,2)+3} 1' file.sql
insert into info.names values  (38 , 'John', 'C', 2);
insert into info.names values  (39 , 'Mark', 'C', 1);
insert into info.names values  (40 , 'Bob', 'C', 5);
```

Comment: [See this document for details on using FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)

Comment: I noted that your code suppresses opening parenthesis. Ex:  insert into info.names values  (38 , 'John', '(C)', 2);. The output would be:      insert into info.names values   (41  , "John", " C)", 2);

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I'm not a awk guru, so there are some things I don't understand. Here is what I did, but it sure is a lot messier than you all's answers.

```
sed -n -r 's/^insert .*\(([0-9]+),.*;/\1/p' Names.sql | while read line; do grep "^insert into info.names values ($line," Names.sql | while read SQLLine; do OLDID=$(echo "$SQLLine" | sed -n -r 's/^insert .*\(([0-9]+),.*;/\1/p'); NEWID=$(expr 2 + $OLDID); sed -n -r "s/(insert into info.names values \()[0-9]+(, .*)/\1$NEWID\2/p" <(echo "$SQLLine"); done; done
```

Thank you guys

Comment: I think this was down voted because it's not a great answer. You probably put it here to show what your code was. You can move this as is, into your question to show that  you tried to solve the problem. Then delete this answer, so regain your lost reputation points. Good luck.